# Python Selenium 'WebDriver' object has no attribute error

Tags: python, selenium, attributes, web-scraping, attributeerror

I'm trying to scrape some javascript-generated content from a Chinese-language website.  I'm using Selenium (and Python) since I can't scrape the javascript content directly.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.selenium import selenium 

import time
import urllib2
import httplib
import urllib
import re
import base64

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://www...") # Load page (redacted here, but any works)
browser.get_body_text() #Attempt to scrape body text
```

And I get the following error:

```
'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'get_body_text'
```

In fact, I can't seem to call any commands in the selenium.selenium class. No doubt I'm overlooking something very obvious. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the version you are using,, for version `2.21.3` this function is not available

Comment: also are you sure `from selenium.selenium import selenium ` works

Comment: Thanks @avasal for the reply! I'm using 2.25.0. Not entirely sure if `from selenium.selenium import selenium` is working here but not sure how else to import commands from that class. Certainly not throwing up errors and have seen others using this code.

Comment: try to execute each of these lines one by one in python prompt.. you will hit the error properly

Comment: Unfortunately in the prompt it still throws up the same for the last command: `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'get_body_text'`

Comment: execute the cmd `dir(browser)` on the prompt, you will find out all the attributes browser object

Comment: Ah! Thanks! Using `dir(browser)`, it looks like the browser object doesn't have the `get_body_text` attribute. But if I instantiate Selenium using `browser = selenium(....)`, the browser object has access to the `get_body_text` attribute attribute. As a Selenium newbie, now I have to figure out how to rejigger the rest of the code to make it work with this kind of instantiation, since it's throwing up new errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You only need `from selenium import webdriver`.
2. Execute `html= browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//html")` to get the html element on the page, the largest element.  (You can do this any number of ways, and select any number of elements. )
3. Execute `html.text` to return the text of the page.

`.text` is a method of an `element` object.  Step 2 is the assignment of the `element` to the name `html`.