# Unable to click on element with link in selenium python

Tags: python, button, selenium, hyperlink

I am trying to interact with a sign out button but I just can't seem to click on it using link text or xpath.

I have tried following these answers with no luck:

- [Why Cant I Click an Element in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511059/why-cant-i-click-an-element-in-selenium?rq=1)
- [Unable to click link using selenium webdriver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811624/unable-to-click-link-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from xatu.tests.base import login
from xatu.tests.bagon import BagonBaseTestCase


class BasicTestCase(BagonBaseTestCase):

    @login
    def test_logout(self):
        self._wait_until_id_presents("quotes-form")
        WebDriverWait(self, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/login/clear']/i")))
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/login/clear']/i").click()
        self.implicitly_wait(2)
        self._title_check("Login")
```

The first line under test_logout calls a function that waits for a certain element to appear on the webpage so I can see that the page has been loaded. Then I try to click the sign out button.

This is the HTML(element is at class="btn" href="/login/clear"):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top screen-only">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
            <a class="brand" href="/">
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                <p class="pull-right" style="margin-top: 4px; margin-left: 4px;">
                    <a class="btn" href="/login/clear">
                        <i class="icon-off"/>
                             Sign out
                    </a>
                </p>
                <p class="navbar-text pull-right">                         Logged-in as D. V.                  Lauper                     </p>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try finding by link_text, the element can't be found. Running this code gives me a stacktrace error saying:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

Edit: I've tried Saifur's answer and updated my code to his answer but now I get: AttributeError: 'BasicTestCase' object has no attribute 'find_element'. I've tried changing "self" to "self.browser" as an argument in WebDriverWait() but I would then get my original error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `explicit wait` and relative`xpath`

like `//a[@href='/login/clear']/i`

```
from xatu.tests.base import login
from xatu.tests.bagon import BagonBaseTestCase  

class BasicTestCase(BagonBaseTestCase):

    @login
    def test_logout(self):
        self._wait_until_id_presents("quotes-form")
        WebDriverWait(self, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/login/clear']/i")))      
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/login/clear']/i").click()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(2)
        self._title_check("Login")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get an error running your code though. AttributeError: 'BasicTestCase' object has no attribute 'find_element'. I tried changing the "self" in WebDriverWait to "self.browser" but I would get my original error. Also I believe you were missing an extra parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention.I corrected the `)`. And, you should be passing the driver instance inside ` WebDriverWait(self, 10)` whatever it is and please make sure you have imported the correct references as well. See [this](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: Are you still getting the `exception`?

Comment: I don't get the exception. Just that Attribute error when I run your code. There are some error that pop up in the Traceback from the selenium expected_conditions pakcage.

Comment: It did not. The test stopped and failed because of that Attribute error. I'm using nosetests by the way if that helps.

Comment: As I said you need to import `from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909884/python-selenium-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-error)

Comment: I had those imported when I ran my test but I still get the attribute error. I've updated my code in my question so you can see what I have now.

Comment: Can you share the line where you instantiate the driver?

Comment: self.browser = webdriver.Firefox() This is in another file. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Could be a problem how you call the classes. try this instead and see if this works `from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.get('http://url.com/')
#something to log in
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/login/clear']/i")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/login/clear']/i").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver._title_check("Login")`

Comment: I implemented your code and I get the same error that I originally received. "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with." Would there be a way to look for an element that matches the href and then click on it? Maybe a get_attribute command?

Answer (score 1):

You need an explicit wait.  [See docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits).  Example code:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//a[@href="/login/clear"]')))
```

And then just click the element.

```
element.click()
```

Note I added my answer b/c -- in my tests at least -- you don't need to worry about the `italics` tag.  That's for the text, not the button -- and you're not clicking the text.  So find `By.XPATH` and select a unique attribute (i.e., the `href` in this case and *very likley* not the `class` attr), and then click your element.

EDIT:

please try this line:

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//a[@class="btn" and @href="/login/clear"]')))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I tried your method I got a timeout issue. It actually couldn't find it for some reason within 30 seconds which should be more then enough time since the webpage loads within about 2 seconds when I'm clicking through manually. I also changed "driver" to "self.browser" since that is my variable that points to webdriver.FireFox()

Comment: @AlphaFoxtrot so is it working or do you need a bit more assistance?  I'm at my computer this morning and would happily do what I can.  let me know!

Comment: More assistance would be appreciated! When I run your code I would get a timeout issue. I don't get my original error however, the error now is: "raise TimeoutException(message) TimeoutException: Message: " There is no message since I have none but couldn't find the element within the time you gave it. The only thing I changed in your code was "driver" in WebDriverWait() to "self.browser"

Comment: I've updated my code according to Saifur's answer and I'm working with him as well to try and solve this problem. I get a different error with his code than yours.

Comment: @AlphaFoxtrot okay, try his/her stuff and then, if it doesn't work, let me know.  I'm happy to help, but I'm sure you and Saifur can get it.  Let me know!  Thanks!

Comment: @AlphaFoxtrot did you get it?

Comment: I did not get it yet. I'm still waiting for a response from Saifur.

Comment: @AlphaFoxtrot have you tried my code?  if you want help presently, I need you to be available for rapid chat -- no minutes-long delays.  I can assist.  If you're getting a timeout exception when you run my code, we can likely get this solved quickly, but I need to know what you're seeing and have meetings this afternoon (so we'll need to work quickly).

Comment: If it's at all possible, can we work on this tomorrow?

Comment: Hey, are you still able to help?

Comment: @AlphaFoxtrot yes, but today's shot for me.  chime in tomorrow and we can finish the job.  I'll need you to be on the ball.

Comment: @AlphaFoxtrot let's get cracking! :)